# angular material components style is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend

Angular version : 14

OS : Linux Ubuntu

I'm using Angular Material default components like matInput, but it does not look as expected :
my component looks like :

[image]

but it should looks like this : [image]

I used the same code snippet in the documentation but I always get this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved after importing **MatInputModule**

in app.module.ts :

```
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
```

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately. Of course all my material design imports are in a separate ts file which I then import into app.module. Something is missing. I still get the ugly thing you got above!